# Entropy and Likelihood Relationship

Tags: entropy

This is a theoretical question.

Suppose that I have a sample s1 coming from distribution K, and a sample s2 coming from distribution M. But I don't know what K or M are. I hypothesize that s1 and s2 are coming from distribution T. I plug in s1 and s2 to pdf of T and calculate their likelihoods, say L(s1), L(s2).  If I know differential entropies of K and M, being H(K) and H(M) respectively, can I find a relation between L(s1) and L(s2) in terms of H(K) and H(M). Basically what I am trying to show is something along the lines of this:

$\frac {L(s1)}{L(s2)} \sim \frac {e^{H(K)}} {e^{H(M)}}$

Is this even meaningful?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that maximizing the likelihood of the data is equivalent to minimizing the [Kullback-Liebler](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeEntropy.html) distance between the hypothesized distribution family, T, and K or M. The kullback-Liebler distance is related to entropy, but its not as simple as your assumed proportional model. See also [link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

Comment: I understand. Since I don't know the distribution it is difficult to calculate KL distance. Basically I am trying to get an approximation for increasing number of samples.

Comment: I see. How do you know H() without knowing the distributions for K and M? Doesn't the differential entropy require the density function? See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DifferentialEntropy.html

Comment: I figure, there are other ways to estimate the entropy from data without knowing the density function.

Comment: I don't think that is true. Imagine if the distribution, T, you selected is way off from K or M..then the ratio of likelihoods would not be very useful in estimating the ratio. The likelihood under a given model is only indirectly related to the true entropy of the distributions.